# Ngmap select ng-repeat marker from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-map

I am using  https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps directive in my project

Following is a code sample in which markers are drawn on the map

```
<map id="map" style="height:450px" zoom="4" zoom-to-include- markers='auto' center="{[{center.lat}]},{[{center.long}]}" on-center-changed="centerChanged()">
<marker id={[{$index}]} animation="DROP" ng-repeat="location in locations" position="{[{location.latitude}]},{[{location.longitude}]}" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker> 

</map>
```

I now have to select these markers from a javascript function.
Selecting marker by id gives marker as a dom element as shown below

```
<marker id="1" animation="DROP" ng-repeat="location in locations" position="10.0050407,76.3459498" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom" class="ng-scope"></marker>
```

instead of google maps marker object

Is there someway i can select marker initialised through ng-repeat as a google maps marker object from javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `Marker` object by using angular's scope. I don't see your JS code but from [Angularjs-Google-Maps example](http://ngmap.github.io/drawings.html#/marker-remove#marker-remove) each marker can be referred to by `$scope.map.markers[key]` where `$scope.map.markers` is the array of markers in your scope.

```
var app=angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('MarkerRemoveCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.positions = [{lat:37.7699298,lng:-122.4469157}];
  $scope.addMarker = function(event) {
    var ll = event.latLng;
    $scope.positions.push({lat:ll.lat(), lng: ll.lng()});
  }
  $scope.deleteMarkers = function() {
    $scope.positions = [];
  };
  $scope.showMarkers = function() {
    for (var key in $scope.map.markers) {
      $scope.map.markers[key].setMap($scope.map);
    };
  };
  $scope.hideMarkers = function() {
    for (var key in $scope.map.markers) {
      $scope.map.markers[key].setMap(null);
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: thanx a lot,it worked great.Is there some place where i can find the related documentaion?

Comment: Here: http://ngmap.github.io/ and here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference